# minimize the difference between adjacent vertices for an un-directed graph

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Suppose we have a undirected graph [image] and each vertex [image] has a initial weight [image]. The weight for each vertex is actually a rotation (in radium). I want to minimize the difference between [image] and [image], [image] such that the difference [image] is less than [image]. In order to adjust the difference [image], we are allowed to add or subtract multiples of [image] to [image] as needed, i.e. [image].

I was  wondering if there is a graph or optimization related method can solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Does this mean the goal is to find a new weight assignment to the nodes?

Comment: Yes, I need to update the new weight to the inconsistent  vertex v_j (the difference that is more than PI to the current vertex v_i)

Comment: The objective is to obtain a weight assignment in which no edge weight exceeds `pi`? Please clarify the requirement that the graph is undirected; the weight difference per edge seems to depend on the edge's direction.

Comment: Yes, the edge does not have a weight.

Comment: So for each edge, there are two differences (one in every direction) which both should be smaller than `pi`?

Comment: Yes, that is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little bit confusing, but have you tried these algorithms?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm

Comment: The links are to Dijkstra's algorithm and Prim's algorithm. These calculate shortest paths and minimum spanning trees.

Comment: Exactly, you can calculate the shortest paths, hence knowing how and which edges you can shorten in order to decrease the difference.

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to find a shortest path between two vertices. I want to adjust the weight of each vertex such that, the difference between adjacent vertices v_i and v_j is with PI.

Comment: Yes but those algorithms work with edge's weight, so i think it might help you. You could run those algorithms and check if the weight never exceeds pi.

Comment: Does any one have some new idea?